# update multiple data codeigniter with checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am trying to update multiple data through AJAX but I have tried several times, but the data has not changed, please help to fix it in order to run perfectly.

Controllers:

```
function update_notif() {
    $this->My_model->update_multiple();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 
                '<div class="callout callout-warning">
                    <h4>Success</h4>
                </div>');                   
}
```

Models:

```
function update_multiple() {
    $update = $this->input->post('id_pesan');
    for ($i=0; $i < count($update) ; $i++) { 
        $data = array('notif' => 0);            
        $this->db->where('id', $delete[$i]);
        $this->db->update('my_table', $data);               
    }
}
```

Views:

```
<button type="button" id="btn_delete" ></button>

<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="selecctall" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Telp</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($show_data as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="select_update" name="select_update[]" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->no; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->nama; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->telp; ?></td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
    <?php } } ?>
</table>
```

Ajax:

```
var getVar = [];  
$(".select_update:checked").each(function() {  
        getVar.push($(this).val());
}); 

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'id_pesan='+getVar,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response)
    {
        if(response){
            location.reload();
        }           
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does your Ajax looks like?
I think you have to change
`$update = $this->input->post('select_id');`
into
`$update = $this->input->post('select_update');` or `$this->input->post('select_update[]');`
because of the `name` attribute of your checkboxes and change
`$this->db->where('id', $delete[$i]);`
into
`$this->db->where('id', $update[$i]);`
or use it in a `foreach`

```
function update_multiple() {
    $updates = $this->input->post('select_update');

    foreach ($updates as $update) { 
        $data = array('notif' => 0);            
        $this->db->where('id', $update);
        $this->db->update('my_table', $data);               
    }
}
```

### Update #1

Your Ajax should look like this - keep scope on `data` of `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
  url : url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: $(".select_update:checked").serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) { ... },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... }
});
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. Apparently both our original answers were partly correct and later we were inspired by each-other.

Comment: thanks @UfguFugullu for answer but That's not the problem after I replace still the same

Comment: @irwandwiyanto I think this answer is correct as well in view of your original question. This answer has not taken your edit about the AJAX request into account yet.

Comment: @UfguFugullu I've tried the script you corrected but it appears an ajax error

Comment: Can you show us your errors? Because I don't get any errors if the variable `url` is set before

Comment: So you have an error in your request. You can read the possible reasons for this under `error` section [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings). And you can show us the content of the `errorThrown` parameter

Comment: Ok successful and resolved, the problem occurred on my url path that was wrong thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have pasted your code from your `delete_multiple` method and this is why you use `$delete` instead of `$update` here

```
function update_multiple() {
    $update = $this->input->post('select_id');
    for ($i=0; $i < count($update) ; $i++) { 
        $data = array('notif' => 0);            
        $this->db->where('id', $delete[$i]);
        $this->db->update('my_table', $data);               
    }
}
```

Solution:

```
function update_multiple() {
    $update = $this->input->post('select_id');
    for ($i=0; $i < count($update) ; $i++) { 
        $data = array('notif' => 0);            
        $this->db->where('id', $update[$i]);
        $this->db->update('my_table', $data);               
    }
}
```

Inspired from UfguFugullu, who was apparently inspired by my answer as well:

`select_update` is needed instead of `select_id`

Comment: thanks @Lajos Arpad for answer but That's not the problem after I replace still the same

Comment: @irwandwiyanto your ajax contains id_pesan in the data. Apparently you will need that instead of select_id or my_table. Also, I would like to ask you to define what "still the same" means exactly in your context.

Comment: I want to update the data in the table based on the id in the checklist, but I doubt the problem on the data retrieval on ajax.

Comment: @irwandwiyanto I cannot see your problem. If you do not specify it exactly, then I cannot help you.

Comment: @irwandwiyanto I understand what you want to achieve, but your error message would be extremely helpful, for instance.